# "Impudent", "Insolent" or "Impertient"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

Please have a look on the following example and let me know which choice sounds correct:

> — Yet it was still an encouraging victory for Mourinho’s team and a difficult afternoon for Tottenham Hot spur was probably summed up by the moment Dele Alli, the .......... young player, scored three goals hand over first. [[Source]](https://comparewords.com/impudent/insolent) (with a slight change.)

a. impudent 
b. insolent 
c. impertinent

Based on dictionary definitions, they all mean "rude" to me. But perhaps "impudent" (at least) can be used here properly. I doubt the other two can work either.

**Dictionary definitions:**

---

> **Impudent**: rude and not showing respect, especially towards someone who is older or in a more important position
>
> **Impertinent**: rude and not showing respect, especially towards someone older or in a higher position than you.
>
> **Insolent**: rude and not showing respect.

As you see, the definitions are so close that I have to be able to use them interchangeably.

**Note:** Please consider that the meaning in my question is something absolutely positive.

Comment: It should also be "hand over fist" at the end of the sentence, not "first."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a native English speaker the word I would be compelled to choose (of the three) is *impudent*.

This is because, while all do have similar meanings, "impudent" is most commonly associated with adult and child relationships. For example, a teacher might call a pupil "impudent" if the child behaved as if they knew better than their elder.

It seems best to fit your context of a "young" player seemingly knowing more or having ability greater than their experience would suggest. Interestingly, I noticed that while the dictionary definitions are very similar, the *synonyms* for "impudent" are slightly different and possibly a little softer - words like *cheeky* and *audacious*, rather than *disrespectful* and *insubordinate* which are listed for the other words.

Comment: Agree, impudent is the only one that seems to have a (somewhat) positive connotation.  The other ones are quite negative.

Comment: What about "audacious" @Astralbee. I just found out its meaning and I guess it can work too, but I'm not sure if it has that positive meaning in our minds.